# Any objective-c open source can let me share content to a number of services?

Tags: iphone, open-source, share

I am going to allow user to share content to their fav services, in my iphone app.

The services I want to integrate include:

twitter
facebook
linkedin
tumblr
evernote
instapaper
etc

Any "One ring to rule them all" open source that I can adopt for this?

I know ShareKit would be a good candidate, but I noticed that it stopped updating since Nov 2010, which is one year ago.

Any suggestions for new such kind of kit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharekit is still the best option, but you need to use this version: https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit

It is still actively being developed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't find this updated one. With ShareKit, can I use my own login dialogs? I think ShareKit has its own UI, but I don't want that. Can I use my own dialogs but internally use ShareKit for auth & sharing?

Comment: You can change some of the dialog, it's open source. Since most of the sites use oauth it will display there website on which you login. You can't really change those login's since they are websites. Also you should not do that, it meant that the user will recognize the site and feel save supply it's person detail. Then the site will tell the user what is wants to do with there account.

Comment: thanks for the reply. but ShareKit is using traditional username/password fields for users to input username and password, right? or does it prompt a service specific web page for user to login?

Comment: Just try it and see for your self. Because it really depends on the service.